# Is there a limit on memory allocated using huge pages?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap

I am allocating memory using "huge pages(1MB size)" and using mmap. After allocating 4 GB of memory ,mmap returns fail.

```
mmap(NULL, memsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS |MAP_POPULATE | MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);
```

here memsize = 1GB

I am calling above statement in a loop. Upto 4 iterations it is fine. In 5th iteration mmap is failed.

```
mmap(NULL, memsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS |MAP_POPULATE , -1, 0);
```

Above statement (without hugepages) works perfectly for any number of iterations. Am I missing any information related to hugepages?
I tried "MAP_NORESERVE" flag also as mentioned in [mmap fail after 4GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803152/mmap-fails-when-length-is-larger-than-4gb).

Any sort of information will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `mmap returns fail` -  this is not useful

Comment: How much is available on your system? You can list it using `cat /proc/meminfo | grep HugePages` .  Additional reading: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt

Comment: @KevinDTimm : i checked return value (MAP_FAILED) then only i concluded mmap failed.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks. That did help. Do you have any CLEAR idea about Rsvd and Surp ,how and when they are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the allocated "number of huge pages" in file

```
 /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
```

according to the amount  of memory you want to allocate.
Earlier it says:

```
>cat /proc/meminfo | grep HugePages 
 HugePages_Total = 2500
```

4GB => it has 2048*2Mb= 4Gb

2048 huge pages already consumed.

one more GB of memory need (1GB/2MB= 512) 512 more huge pages. But 2500 - 2048 =452 only left. But you need 512. Thats the problem why mmap failed. If you edit the above mentioned file(/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages) contents to 2560, it allows 5GB. Change it according to the amount of memory you need. Thanks to @ Klas Lindbäck. I referred back [the link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt), small research exposed the working