# Why is the RX ring of a Linux raw socket limited to 4GB in size?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, raw-sockets

**Background**

I'm trying to `mmap()` the RX ring buffer of a raw socket in my **64-bit** Linux application. My ring consists of 4096 blocks of size 1MB each for a total of 4GB. (Note there can be many frames in each 1MB block. [See this doc for background if you're curious.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt))

**Problem**

Unfortunately, there appears to be a 4GB limit on the size of the RX ring buffer when configuring it using `setsockopt()` with option `PACKET_RX_RING`. The implication for me is that I cannot increase either my block size or my ring size any further. My application would benefit from an increase though.

This limit is at least enforced in modern versions of the Linux kernel. [See the source here.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.1/source/net/packet/af_packet.c#L4262)

(Note that there is no issue `mmap()`ing larger than 4GB. I originally stumbled into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803152/mmap-fails-when-length-is-larger-than-4gb?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).)

**Question**

Why is there a limit of 4GB for the RX ring buffer? If it's a bug when migrating this part of the kernel from 32-bit, that would be cool and might be straightforward to patch. But, if there's a more fundamental reason, I'm curious to know what that may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug. I submitted a patch to fix this (now merged):
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fc62814d690cf62189854464f4bd07457d5e9e50

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. Let's examine how the PACKET_MMAP ring buffer structure and its buffers get allocated. This is done at [line 4270](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.1/source/net/packet/af_packet.c#L4270) by calling `alloc_pg_vec`. The structure itself is just an array of pointers and is allocated using `kcalloc`, which imposes an upper limit of 131,072 bytes. If each pointer is 8 bytes in size, then there can be at most 131,072/8 = 16,384 = 2<sup>14</sup> blocks. Each block is allocated using `alloc_one_pg_vec_page`. Note that each block must be contiguous in memory and its size must be a multiple of the page size (4096 bytes). The `order` parameter passed to `alloc_pg_vec` represents the number of pages to be allocated as a power of two for each buffer. There is a limit on the order defined in [mmzone.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.1/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L25), which is `MAX_ORDER` = 11. Therefore, the maximum block size is 4096 * 2<sup>11</sup> = 2<sup>23</sup> = 8 MiB. **This means that the ring overall is limited to 2<sup>37</sup> bytes or 128 GiB**.

I don't know why the check `req->tp_block_size > UINT_MAX / req->tp_block_nr` is performed. It could be because older versions of Linux supported smaller numbers of buffers and buffer sizes (`MAX_ORDER` was 10 in Linux 2.4). But perhaps by removing the check, you can allocate rings up to 128 GiB in size.

Comment: That was fast, Hadi Brais. Thanks for the feedback and for confirming the ring limit of 128GB. I got the same, which prompted me to investigate this further. Time permitting, I'll remove the check, build my own kernel, and see if there is any fallout.